# Why is it true that if $0\leq{}x\leq{1\over2}$ then $(1-x)\geq(2e)^{-x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In something I am reading I find a statement of the form

> Since $0\leq{}x\leq{1\over2}$, we have that $(1 - x)$ is at least $(2e)^{-x}$.

I am not able to figure out why this holds. Why is this true?

Comment: @BarryCipra Thank you, from the context it is true that $x\geq0$. I will change the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be an implicit assumption that $x\geq 0$.

Take logarithms on both sides and note that $\log(1-x) +x \log(2e)$ is concave in $x$.  Hence we only need to check the inequality for $x=1/2$ and $x=0$.

Now,

$$\frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2}{e}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2e}} = (2e)^{-1/2},$$

and

$$1 \geq (2e)^0.$$

Comment: Thank you! I have changed the question to include the condition $x\geq0$.